# How to translate a column from english to french in a dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, translate

I want to translate a column [Month] that has values in English ("January", "February","March", etc) to French ("Janvier", "Février", "Mars", etc) . How can I do that please?
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the benchmarks that I did in the past, `map` was quite fast, as it works in a single column.
[pandas.Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

Something like
`df['month_EN']=df['month'].map({'Janvier':'January',...})`

Answer (score 0):

I think "[pandas.DataFrame.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html?highlight=substi)" might help. It is not a translation but can help you do the task.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).